# Android TelephonyManager is returning null value for telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber(); and getDeviceId();

Tags: telephonymanager

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
 TextView textView, textView1;
 TelephonyManager telephonyManager;

 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     textView = findViewById(R.id.text);
     textView1 = findViewById(R.id.text1);
    
     telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED     && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_PHONE_NUMBERS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{READ_SMS, READ_PHONE_NUMBERS,  READ_PHONE_STATE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }else {
         textView.setText("SimSrNo- "+telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber());
          textView1.setText("DeviceID- "+telephonyManager.getDeviceId());
        
    }


}

  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
     super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
     switch (requestCode) {
         case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) !=   PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            } else {
                textView.setText("SimSrNo- "+telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber());
                textView1.setText("DeviceID- "+telephonyManager.getDeviceId());
                
            }
    }
}
```

}
But it is giving correct value for getDeviceSoftwareVersion(), getSimCarrierIdName().

Have tried various solutions provided on the net but it did not help.
Have also tried solutions suggested while posting this request

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Clarifying that Want to get the SIM Serial Number and Unique Device Id or IMEI Number of Mobile device Programmatically in Android.